# Reconstruct a 2D array from a string

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, I have a string (**b** in the following example) converted from a 2D array (**a**). How can I reconstruct the 2D array from the string?

I guess I am using the wrong function "numpy.fromstring" since **c** here is a 1D array.

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype='float32')
b = a.tostring()
c = numpy.fromstring(b, dtype='float32')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string returned by `a.tostring()` does **not** record the exact shape of `a` any more than it records the type of items (here, `float32`).  `fromstring` **always** returns a 1-D array -- see the docs at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html -- then you have to reshape the array appropriately if need be:

```
>>> c.reshape([2,2])
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]], dtype=float32)
```

As to how you preserve that `[2,2]` shape and `float32` type to be able to restore it -- for both, you need to make your own arrangements!-)

Comment: Thanks! This is a very simple solution that I expect. To clarify, do you mean that some information ([2,2] shape and float32 type) got lost during the convert from array to string?

Comment: @BroCannon yes, the string does **not** record underlying type and shape, so you need to save them separately if you'll later need to reconstruct the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which saves the shape of the array is to use [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). These functions expect files as input, so we'll be using [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to make a file-like string object:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype='float32')
>>> io = StringIO()
>>> numpy.savetxt(io, a)
>>> s = io.getvalue()
>>> s
'1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00\n3.000000000000000000e+00 4.000000000000000000e+00\n'
```

We can recover the array from this string by using `np.loadtxt`, wrapping it in another `StringIO`:

```
>>> numpy.loadtxt(StringIO(s))
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```